# Is it possible to redirect a folder and a subfolder of that folder to different locations?

Tags: .htaccess

Is it possible to redirect a folder and subfolder to different locations within Apache?

For examples, redirect

`/images` to `new-domain.com/images`

and

`/images/uploads/` to `new-domain.com/uploads`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use either a redirect or a rewrite. Have a look at the [mod_rewrite docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/remapping.html).

`Redirect` is easiest. `RedirectMatch` will let you use a regex to be a bit more flexible:

```
RedirectMatch permanent /images(/uploads/)? http://www.example.com/images$1
```

Comment: you are awesome with good solution